# Copying files based on common characters from a key

Tags: r, file-transfer

I am trying to find a way in `R` to copy certain binary files of interest to another folder. I am selecting those files based of a `key`. A sample of which is shown below. The problem is that the numbers in the key has `three` decimal places where as the files have `four`.

For instance how can I tell `R` that if it finds `43.093_-110.531` in a file name then it should copy that file to another folder.

The file names are some thing like this

```
data_43.09375_-110.53125
data_43.09375_-110.59375
```

search key

```
43.093_-110.531
43.093_-110.469
43.093_-110.406
43.156_-110.594
43.156_-110.531
43.156_-110.469
43.156_-110.406
43.156_-110.344
43.156_-110.281
43.218_-110.844
43.218_-110.781
43.218_-110.719
43.218_-110.656
43.218_-110.594
43.218_-110.531
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `substr` to extract and then do `%in%`

```
files[ substr(files, 5, 22) %in% key]
```

Comment: So I don't need a loop since I copying multiple files?

Comment: @Mandalorian Are you looking for a match with the key vector for copying or just subsetting.  If it is a match, then `i1 <- match(key, substr(files, 5, 22))` gives the index of corresponding match between the files and the key.  Then use that index to subset the files and copy it to correpsonding key, `files[i1]`

Comment: Is `files` inside `match` just the path to the folder that contains the files?

Comment: @Mandalorian I assumed your files are in the working directory or else you may have to specify the path in `list.files` i.e. `files <- list.files('path/to/your/folder', full.names = TRUE); i1 <- match(key, substr(basename(files), 5, 22))`

Comment: When I run `i1` I get `NA_Integer_`, is it because, if you look at the example above the file name `data_43.09375_-110.53125` has extra decimal numbers in both numbers i.e. `75` and `25`., but the key only has 3 decimal places `43.093_-110.531`, so `R` takes it as a mismatch and returns `NA`?

Comment: @Mandalorian The `substr` should extract the `43.09375_-110.531`, but your key is now `43.093_-`  In that case, we may need a regex instead of fixed match